# Chrome extension get display information of active screen

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, extension-methods, chrome-extension-manifest-v2

I am creating a chrome extension that can fetch display information [ screen-dimension ] on click-on extension. and I got success in it using, following API

```
chrome.system.display.getInfo();
```

This API is giving information all attached displays [ That's really great tho], but what I actually want is, I want to get display information of that screen on which my chrome browser is open.

**e.g**
I have screens,
screen-one : 1980 * 1280,
screen-two : 1680 * 980,

now if my chrome browser window is open on **screen-two** then the info I want is 1680 * 980, and if my chrome browser window is open on **screen-one** then the info I want is 1980 * 1280.

**Documents Is used**
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/system_display/

I have read the document, maybe I am missing something. So please help me to identify what I am missing here or where I can improve myself

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found any accurate solution using chrome extension API.

But, The approach I used is,

I have created a content script that reads the window object of the active screen and gives me the dimension of that screen by sending messages to my chrome extension.

```
// ContentScript.ts

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, _sender, response) => {
        const {
            screen: { height, width },
            innerHeight,
            innerWidth,
            devicePixelRatio,
        } = window;

        const displayInfo = {
            height: height * devicePixelRatio,
            width: width * devicePixelRatio,
            tabHeight: innerHeight,
            tabWidth: innerWidth,
        };

        if (request.requestType === 'getDisplayInfo' && displayInfo) {
            response(displayInfo);
        }
    });
```

**Thanks**

Comment: how does the height/width of the window multiplied by the devicePixelRatio give you the display dimensions?

Comment: Hi @RyanBuckley, height, and width only give the screen height and width not the depth of the screen, in 4k screens or retina displays or Mac, you can see actual differences like 4k screen size can never be 1440 * 900, but if you can get DPP (depth per pixel) you can get the exact answer by multiplying and DPR do the same thing. and Sorry for the late reply.